# javascript chart library that supports the "follows" on line charts with mobile

Tags: javascript, html, web, charts

I am looking for an html5/css/javascript chart library that supports the "follows" on line charts with mobile.
To be precise on what am I refering to by "follows" on line charts, here are good examples:

- http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html
- https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines

even slightly different, this one would be nice also

- http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/tracking/index.html

I have made some tests using the extensive comparison provided [here](http://kraskniga.blogspot.fr/2012/06/comparison-of-javascript-data.html). Unfortunately, I was not able to find a line chart demo with "follows" that worked "out-of-the-box" with both Chrome and Chrome Android. Chrome is my targeted browser for now, I am writing a non commercial app just for fun.

It seems that most of these implementations are based on :hover css selector which is not available for mobile. I tried to bind the :hover logic with the "touchmove" but it was not straightforward (with rickshaw at the very least).

My question is: am I missing a library or an option in the existing libraries or should I keep on trying to implement my custom logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed amCharts in your list, it does support "follows", for example: 
http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/line-with-duration-on-value-axis/

Note, you should set chart.panEventsEnabled = true in order touch events to work on mobile.

Disclaimer - I am the author of amCharts and amMap.

Comment: Thank you, I was just starting to implement my own code for supporting the "follows" on mobile. I will definitely have a look on amCharts. Sorry for having forgotten you library^^.

Answer (score -1):

you can try echarts, it's really good at rendering large data and does supoort "follow", here's the example and the code

http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/editor.html?c=doc-example/scatter-dataZoom-all

Comment: It is better if you can add the full answer in the answer section, Adding links as an answer is not recommended since later these links can be broken or content of these links could be changed.